# I'm trying to make a AWS CLI query to bring me EC2 instance names + keypair names and it doesn't seem to be working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have a script and it's supposed to bring me all EC2 that aren't beanstalk or clusters, I did that successfully, then, I tried to bring the names of these instances + their keypairs, however, my query doesn't seem to be working.

This is the query that I tried, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, it's supposed to bring me two columns, one with the name and another with the name of the keypairs each EC2 uses.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --output text --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running \
--query 'Reservations[].Instances[?!not_null(Tags[?Key == `elasticbeanstalk:environment-name`] || Tags[?Key == `eks:cluster-name`] )].KeyName | [].Tags[?Key == `Name`].Value'  \
--region us-east-1 --profile dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Your projection has problem.

```bash
aws ec2 describe-instances --output text --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running \
--query 'Reservations[].Instances[?!not_null(Tags[?Key == `elasticbeanstalk:environment-name`] || Tags[?Key == `eks:cluster-name`])] | [].{"InstanceName": Tags[?Key == `Name`].Value | [0], "KeyName": KeyName}'  \
--region us-east-1 --profile dev
```